# Weird artefacts on tire track in sand? Anyone with an idea on this?

Tags: dynamic-paint

I have an animation with a VW Phoenix truck driving along a sand beach.

It creates the desired tire tracks as can be seen. The subdivision of the surface is reasonably good, as can be seen on the tracks which are good for large parts of the movement. The beach surface is evenly subdivided all over.
Still I get every couple of meter these huge sand spikes which you can see on the screenshot.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

The computer has 72 GB of RAM and 2 Xeon X5650 processors and I am using blender 2.82.
Graphics card is an Nvidia GTX 1060 with 6GB. I'm using Cycles with GPU to render.

Thanks for any suggestions, Pretty[image: Screenshot of sand spikes]

Actually I thought I found the reason. The spikes seem to occur where the underlying path Nurbs changes direction. Need to smooth out that curve ;-) And, just for reference, one can set a maximum displacement value created on the surface, which should solve this issue too.

UPDATE BOTH DOES NOT SOLVE THE ISSUE ;-(

Meanwhile I tried subdividing the surface even more, still it does not help. The dynamic paint modifier is last in the stack.

Still looking for a solution.

[image]

Comment: Hi. You should add more details about the involved meshes (brush and canvas) or other particularities likes scales and rotations, etc. and what drives the animation (a curve ?)

Comment: And perhaps add also some close picture of the issue (the current image is very far pov). Can also upload the .blend if you want to (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Thanks, here some more details.
The rig I am using for the car is Car-Rig-Pro which, in principle works wunderful.
The path is a NURBS curve with a shrinkwrap modifier attached to the beach.
The beach surface is a single mesh, which has a subdivision modifier (3) with the same value for render & viewport and quality. Catmull, use creases, smooth keep corners, optimal display off.
Dynamic paint has max displace set to 40mm, non incremental, anti-aliasing on.
Unfortunately I can not upload the file due to copyright.

Comment: I added another image above. Btw. adding substeps sends the car all over the place.

Comment: Have you checked if something (car, wheel, sand) has inverted normals?

Comment: I'll look into that, but as the tracks are good for the most part, thats unlikely, no?
The sand is one big meshwithout any interuptions.

Comment: What about normals, as asked just before?

Comment: Normals on the beach point downwards (=the normal lines are below the surface). On the tires its hard to see, but as part of the tracks are generated I correctly, I have a hard time to see why it could be the normals. Still, I look into the tires right now by changing them. I'll let you know once I know. Thanks so far!

Comment: You mean, normals for the beach are not up? That could be that, so. You should try to invert them, just to see the result.

Comment: You're a star! Flipping the normals of the beach did it. I do not understand why, but it did the trick! THANK YOU SO MUCH!